# Android/Eclipse: where to write command-lines like "emulator -wipe-data"?

Tags: android, eclipse, command-line, emulation

Many blogs mention writing command lines to do different stuffs...but I don't know where to write these command lines! For example, I want to clean my emulator with `emulator -wipe-data` but where should I put this?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Open command prompt & goto

```
android-sdk-windows\tools
```

Then for the following command:

```
emulator -avd -wipe-data
```

use something like:

```
emulator -avd myandroidavd -wipe-data
```

Comment: Thanks ! But how to open "command prompt" ? :) Sorry for my stupid questions... (on Mac ? And on PC ?)

Comment: Check this: "How to use command prompt and cmd commands" http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=foYsmpDrYjY

Comment: Thanks ! It works on my PC but not on my Mac. Somebody knows how to clean the AVD on a Mac ?

Comment: The emulator launches after the wipe, is it possible to disable that?

Answer (score 1):

to set the wipe option on Mac, with the Android SDK Manager running, click the start button to launch an AVD.  A Launch Options window opens.  There is a Wipe User Data checkbox about half way down.

Answer (score 1):

So Simple Solution.
If you have Ubuntu System,
Then Go to this path:

```
/home/rahul/Android/Sdk/emulator
```

If you have other Operating System, Then go to this path according to you.
After Check List of Emulators using this command:

```
./emulator -list-avds
```

It will show thw result look like:

```
Pixel_3_XL_API_29
Pixel_3_XL_API_29_2
Pixel_3_XL_API_29_3
```

After, All Wipe Command:

```
emulator -avd Pixel_3_XL_API_29_3 -wipe-data
```

Answer (score -4):

You can follow the accepted answer or simply open the AVD manager and follow the below demonstration to wipe the emulator data.

[image]

Click the down arrow icon next to the edit icon.

[image]

Click wipe data.
[image]

Comment: this is not from command line

Comment: @pepan, Thanks for finding this out after 2 and a half years of posting this answer. This answer is for the newbies who can do the same approach without a terminal.