# Remove password from Android Emulator?

Tags: android-emulator

How to get rid of/get past the "Enter password to unlock" prompt in the Android emulator?

Wish I could explain how this got turned on but its probably my fault. I've been trying to use the android maven plugin to build apps for a custom kernel to get tooled up to build a custom device admin app. I recall finding a "API Demos" app in the emulator with and using its "Device Admin" button to register an account with google (even tho I'd already registered). Google refused every account name I could think of so I gave up. Or maven might have compiled a sample device admin app into that kernel.

I am not really sure how it got in this state. Will investigate once I get the emulator back in a usable state, if that's even possible.

Comment: Nothing is accessible, even settings. Just "enter password to unlock".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Emulator "To Start Android, enter your password" and it reminds me the password is wrong"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44517420/android-emulator-to-start-android-enter-your-password-and-it-reminds-me-the-p)

Answer (score 3):

This seems to have fixed it:

```
emulator -avd AVD2.2 \
-system out/target/product/generic/system.img \
-initdata out/target/product/generic/userdata.img \
-wipe-data
```

Comment: If anyone is wondering where to type these commands, see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6831698/android-eclipse-where-to-write-command-lines-like-emulator-wipe-data.

Answer (score 2):

All applications and files that you have deployed to the Android Emulator are stored in a file named userdata-qemu.img located in the C:\Users\.android\avd\.avd folder. For example, I have an AVD named Android_2.2_Emulator; hence, the userdata-qemu.img file is located in the C:\Users\Wei-Meng Lee.android\avd\Android_2.2_Emulator.avd folder.

If you want to restore the emulator to its original state (to reset it, that is), simply delete the userdata-qemu.img file.

Comment: C:\Users\{username}\.android\.avd\{avdname}.avd\userdata-qemu.img more specifically :-P

Answer (score -1):

**open** `C:\Users\User\.android\avd\your_device.avd\emulator-user.ini`
you get something similar to this

```
window.x = 16
window.y = 35
uuid = 1581076634048
```

the password in this case is `1581076634048`
it worked for me

Comment: alternative to `C:\Users\User\.android\avd\your_device.avd\emulator-user.ini ` would be the folder where the avd is located