# How to find and removed password with adb

Tags: android, adb, android-virtual-device

I run avd in eclipse and i set a password for avd.
I want find and remove the password with avd.
I saw this [link](http://www.tricksmode.com/2013/10/5-ways-to-bypass-crack-unlock-android-password-face-pin-or-pattern-lock-without-flashing.html) and all description is about real phone but i doesn't worked in avd.
Did i need another things?

Comment: Why not delete the AVD and create a new one?

Comment: i haven't any problem with my avd:)). i want find a way to find and remove pass in avd and phone with adb. it's a research.

Comment: please see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8996762/remove-password-from-android-emulator)