# Android Emulator "To Start Android, enter your password" and it reminds me the password is wrong"

Tags: android

I just installed Android Studio,  when I run the Android Emulator it says: "To Start Android, enter your password" and it reminds me the password is wrong".
How can i fix it?
I would be very glad if someone has an answer for this

Comment: Try adding a new AVD.

Answer (score 42):

Wiping data in Android Virtual Device Manager works for me.

Tools -> Android -> AVD Manager -> Actions (triangle down) -> Wipe Data

Comment: You can also call wipe data from command line with sdk tool emulator.exe (using xamarin on windows my android sdk path is `C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\tools`) with the command `emulator -avd my_avd_name -wipe-data`. You can also list avd names with comand `emulator -list-avds`

Comment: They removed "AVD Manager" in VS2019 tools menu?

Answer (score 17):

Setting the ANDROID_SDK_HOME as described in a previous answer didn't work for me (although it did start using the folder I specified, placing a new `.android` folder there and using it)

Neither did doing a Factory Reset by right-clicking on the device in the Android Device Manager in Visual Studio 2019.

The only thing that worked for me was making sure that the checkbox for Google APIs was checked, and making sure it was on x86 of course; selecting x86_64 grays out the two checkboxes. 
Note that it doesn't matter whether I use a Pixel or some other device such as a Nexus; it apparently always needs to use the image with the Google APIs.

[image: Edit Device screen]

Answer (score 11):

I had this problem on my Visual Studio 2017 Community development setup and here is how I solved it:

1. Shut down the AVD if it's running.
2. While in the Android Device Manager, select the AVD with the problem.
3. Right click or select the context sensitive menu and select "Factory Reset".
4. Start the AVD again and it should boot normally.

*Just be sure that all the data you've saved on the AVD will be lost once you factory-reset it.

Answer (score 10):

**Windows**

Hyosoo Kim is right about the problem (non-ascii characters in the user directory), but I think this is an easier solution :

**Add a new User Environment Variable :**

Control Panel -> System -> Advanced System Settings -> Environment Variables

Add a new user variable

Name : **ANDROID_SDK_HOME**

Value : the path to a directory not in your user home (C:\Android for example)

There you go !

Comment: Raphael is right, downvoter sucks. When I created this environment variable and set it to a directory not containing latin2 character, it started to work again. Btw do not get fooled by variable name. The variable must not point to a location of the SDK. It is preferences location variable.

Comment: And don't forget to restart Android Studio after adding environment variable and before creating AVD.

Comment: Creating environment variable ANDROID_SDK_HOME as you say and checking my system language to be English work for me

Answer (score 8):

In VS2017 version 15.9.3,perform the following steps :

1. Open **Tools > Android Device Manager ** and search the device that you debug
2. Click with **Right Click** on it
3. Choose **"Factory Reset"**
   [image]
4. And you will get brand new device, ready to debug.

**Good Luck!**

Answer (score 1):

If your user directory contains non-ascii characters, then try to change user name to English name.
I had same problem and it was solved when I logged on to root account.

Answer (score 1):

My case was the described by Hyosoo Kim. I solved the problem renaming my user profile folder (following these intructions [Change the Name of a User Profile Folder in Windows 10](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/89060-change-name-user-profile-folder-windows-10-a.html)) and deleting the folder .android under my profile folder.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue but was using Visual Studio 2017 and Xamarin rather than Android Studio. Doing a Factory reset in the Android Device Manager in Visual Studio didn't work for me.

So I installed Android Studio and as per Yao's answer, launched the AVD Manager from in there then selected 'Wipe Data' from the triangle dropdown. This resolved the issue and I was able to use the emulator from within Visual Studio again.

The Android Device Manager in Visual Studio seems to be missing some features compared to the one in Android Studio, so this solution is the only one I could find that worked.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue when trying to use the x86_64 processor, even when I created a brand new device. Using the x86 processor in the device properties resolved the issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

Open

> ...\USER.android\AVD_NAME.avd\emulator-user.ini

There's a "uuid" which contains the password.

For example:

```
uuid = 1568486155483
```

And `1568486155483` is the password.

Worked 4 me :)

Comment: It worked but said something along the lines of "The password is correct but data is corrupt. Perform factory reset." I ended up deleting the AVD and creating it from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

This solution working for me on VS2017/Xamarin

1. Turn Off your device
2. Open MS-DOS console
3. Start your device with following command:

> emulator.exe -verbose -feature WindowsHypervisorPlatform -avd 
>   "My_device_name" -prop emu.uuid="your_id" -skip-adb-auth -wipe-data

4. Turn Off your device (no more password is needed)
5. Launch your device with 'Android Device Manager'

More information will be available in your log file:
See most recent file here:
C:\Users\"my_account_name"\AppData\Roaming\XamarinDeviceManager

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Shutdown the AVD (if it's running).
2. Go to the config file of this AVD, The default location is the following (where `AVD_NAME` is the AVD name, and `USER` is your system user):

   - Mac and Linux: `~/.android/avd/AVD_NAME.avd/config.ini`
   - XP: `C:\Documents and Settings\USER\.android\AVD_NAME.avd\config.ini`
   - Vista - `C:\Users\USER\.android\AVD_NAME.avd\config.ini`
   - Win10, `C:\Users\<user>\.android\avd\Android_Accelerated_x86_Oreo.avd\config.ini`
3. Remove any blank line from the beginning and the end of the file.
4. Finally, run your AVD directly from the AVD Manager.

hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your Users folder > .android > avd folder > then delete the avds configuration or wipe out everything.

Then go back to your VS and click Android Emulator. VS will show you their recommended configuration. Use that and run your project with that emulator.

Answer (score 0):

Just wipe your device data. Works for me.
[image]