# Is there a command line to wipe data of a virtual devices in Android Studio 3.4.2?

Tags: android-studio

I need often to wipe data of a virtual device in Android Studio with Windows 10, is there a command line to wipe data of a virtual devices ?

Now I have to do it in Android Studio UI.

**Image**
[image]

**Added Content**

I do by [Wipe data/Factory reset through ADB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10817721/wipe-data-factory-reset-through-adb), but I can't get the correct result.

**WipeDate.bat**

```
e:
cd E:\Android_SDK\platform-tools
adb shell
recovery --wipe_data
cmd
```

**Result**
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wipe data/Factory reset through ADB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10817721/wipe-data-factory-reset-through-adb)

Comment: Thanks! Would you please see the Added Content of this question?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android/Eclipse: where to write command-lines like “emulator -wipe-data”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6831698/android-eclipse-where-to-write-command-lines-like-emulator-wipe-data)

Answer (score 27):

Open the terminal

`android-sdk\tools>emulator -avd -wipe-data`

Command Usage

`emulator -avd Your_Device_Name -wipe-data`

`emulator -avd androidavd2 -wipe-data`

For handling of Android Virtual Devices use can use `avdmanager` for more details see this link [Command Line Tool For Android Emulator](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/avdmanager) . This page also contains complete official documentation for using command line tools for doing almost everything using command line, like creating, deleting an avd, installing apk on the emulator and running you app on avd.

Hope this solves your issue.

Comment: Wow. You answered a question that has a bounty, but you won't get the bounty because the person who asked it is AFK. Sorry :(

Comment: Oh i see... @AndrewKoster

Comment: @HelloCW its fine :)